# ASP.MVC 5 Dropdown on Create page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I have 2 models, and i need to show Groups dropdown on Students create page. Now i have page, where i can choose group, but i don't see choosed variant after submit (student.Group is null in [POST]Index). What's can be the problem?

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Group")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.MyGroups = db.Groups.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id, FIO, Group")] Student student)
    {
        // Here student.Group is null
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(student);
    }
 }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model TestSystem.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.MyGroups = new SelectList(ViewBag.MyGroups, "Id", "Name");
}

...

   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Group, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Group, (SelectList)ViewBag.MyGroups) )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Group, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Let me know if the answer below solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot post complex objects like `Group` via an HTML form element like a select box (`@Html.DropDownListFor`). You should use just the group id as part of your view model that is bound on form post and then use that to construct or lookup the correct `Group` object in your controller.

## Model

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Group")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

## View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupId, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupId, (SelectList)ViewBag.MyGroups) )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupId, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

## Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id, FIO, GroupId")] Student student)
{
    // Lookup group via GroupId, or construct a new Group object on `student`

    // build student for database and save

    ...

    return View(student);
}
```

However, you probably should not be using your `Student` class as a view model directly either if it represents your data entity. Create a separate model `StudentViewModel` that implements the form elements you need on the page.

## Example

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Group")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupId, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupId, (SelectList)ViewBag.MyGroups) )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupId, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "GroupId")] StudentViewModel model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Lookup group via model.GroupId, or construct a new Group object
        // var group = db.Groups.GetByGroupId(model.GroupId);

        var student = new Student { Group = group };

        db.Students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(student);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It solves my problem.
 p.s.: how to mark answer as solution?